# How to store additional_settings value when adding a node?

Tags: 7, database, nodes

Since storing node type `additional_settings` is done without the need for calling any other hooks, I quite have a problem to store a simple string from `additional_settings` on node add form.

After the admin enables a feature on the node type form he/she is offered the following form when adding a node:

```
$form['MY_MODULE'] = array(
  '#type'         => 'fieldset',
  '#title'        => 'Custom String',
  '#collapsible'  => TRUE,
  '#collapsed'    => FALSE,
  '#weight'       => -99,
  '#group'        => 'additional_settings',
  '#attached'     => array(
    'js' => array(
      'vertical-tabs' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/MY_MODULE.js',
    ),
  ),
);
$form['MY_MODULE']['MY_MODULE_string'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Enter a string'),
  '#default_value' => '',
);
```

I've seen other modules, like [`comment.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/7) or [`nodeapi_example.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.module/7) where they then call [`hook_node_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and I tried that as well. I happily can see my string within `dpm($node)`, but then I'll get a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found`. Do I have to follow any naming conventions on how to name the table? Or do I have to create it first (where)?:

```
db_insert('MY_MODULE_string')
->fields(array(
    'nid' => $node->nid,
    'vid' => $node->vid,
    'string' => $node->MY_MODULE_string,
))
->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I simply had to look into [`nodeapi_example.install`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example!nodeapi_example.install/7) to find out about [`hook_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) to create a new database table where I then can save my values to. So I created an install file and put the following code inside:

```
function MY_MODULE_schema() {
  $schema['MY_MODULE_string'] = array(
    'description' => 'Stores information of extended content.',
    'fields' => array(
      'nid'    => array(
        'description' => 'Node ID that the string is applied to.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'vid' => array(
        'description' => 'Revision ID, as we are tracking strings with node revisions',
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
      ),
      'url' => array(
        'description' => 'MY MODULE string',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 19,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('vid'),
    'indexes' => array(
      'nid'   => array('nid'),
    ),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```